# iPhone 5: AVCaptureExposureModeAutoFocus not supported in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

I am trying to implement a camera application using AVFoundation. I want to use the AVCaptureExposureModeAutoFocus to set the exposurePointOfInterest at a point, and then lock the exposure as explained by Apple's documentation:

> **AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose:** the device automatically adjusts the
>   exposure once and then changes the exposure mode to
>   AVCaptureExposureModeLocked.

This is the function that I used:

```
-(void)autoExposeAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [videoInput device];
    if([device isExposurePointOfInterestSupported] && [device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose]){
        if([device lockForConfiguration:NULL]){
            [device setExposurePointOfInterest:point];
            [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
            NSLog(@"Exposure point of intereset has been set to (%f,%f)",point.x, point.y);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the auto exposure at the desired point just never happened. As I debugged using the NSLog below, it turned out that `AVCaputreExposureModeAutoExpose` is not supported. Whereas, if I used `AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExpose`, it would run perfectly.

I don't understand this; is this true that this `AVCaputreExposureModeAutoExpose` is not supported in iPhone 5's back camera running iOS7? Anyone has any clue? THANKS!

**Debug Code:**

```
NSLog(@"issupported: %hhd", [device isExposurePointOfInterestSupported]);
NSLog(@"ismodesupported: %hhd" ,[device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose]);

**Result:**
issupported: 1
ismodesupported: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this question on Apple developer forum and got answered by Brad Ford (Core Media Engineering) the speaker for Camera with AV Foundation in Apple's WWDC.

Here's his [answer](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/218205?tstart=0):

> **Correct.  AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose, while defined in the
> header, is not currently implemented on any iOS device.**
>
> You can
> however implement it in your own code by setting your desired point of
> interest, then calling
> setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure, and then
> listen (key-value observe) the "isAdjustingExposure" property of
> AVCaptureDevice to know when the exposure finishes adjusting.  As soon
> as it does, setExposureMode to AVCaptureExposureModeLocked.

Comment: The relevant key is actually "adjustingExposure".