# How to produce AVFoundation Camera Images as bright as those taken with the native camera?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, avfoundation, brightness

I've played with AutoFocus, and AutoExposure, AutoWhiteBalance, and LowLightBoost, but still can get the camera images to display as bright as those viewed/captured using the native iPhone 5 camera.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Below is the main function that sets the auto camera features when the screen is pressed. The Autofocus works. But not sure if the auto exposure, White balance, and LowLightBoost are working as supposed too because dark items viewed don't brighten as well as with the native camera. 
Most of the code below is taken from the AVCam Example posted on the iosDev Center Site.

Thanks in advance!

```
- (IBAction)focusAndExposeTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint devicePoint = [(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:[gestureRecognizer view]]];
    [self focusWithMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus exposeWithMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose whiteBalanceWithMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance atDevicePoint:devicePoint monitorSubjectAreaChange:YES];
}

- (void)focusWithMode:(AVCaptureFocusMode)focusMode exposeWithMode:(AVCaptureExposureMode)exposureMode whiteBalanceWithMode:(AVCaptureWhiteBalanceMode)whiteBalanceMode atDevicePoint:(CGPoint)point monitorSubjectAreaChange:(BOOL)monitorSubjectAreaChange{
dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self videoDeviceInput] device];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
    {
        if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] && [device isFocusModeSupported:focusMode])
        {
            [device setFocusMode:focusMode];
            [device setFocusPointOfInterest:point];
        }
        NSLog(@"Pre-Exposure Mode Support?: %hhd", [device isExposurePointOfInterestSupported]);
        if ([device isExposurePointOfInterestSupported] && [device isExposureModeSupported:exposureMode])
        {
            [device setExposureMode:exposureMode];
            [device setExposurePointOfInterest:point];
        }
        NSLog(@"Pre-White Balance mode Support? %hhd", [device isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:whiteBalanceMode]);
        if ([device isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:whiteBalanceMode])
        {
            [device setWhiteBalanceMode:whiteBalanceMode];
        }
        NSLog(@"Pre Low light mode: %hhd", [device isLowLightBoostSupported]);
        if ([device isLowLightBoostSupported]){
            [device setAutomaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable:YES];
        }
        [device setSubjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled:monitorSubjectAreaChange];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the problem lies on your `AVCaptureExposureMode`. As you can refer from my thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361087/iphone-5-avcaptureexposuremodeautofocus-not-supported-in-ios-7), iOS 7 currently does not support `AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose` on any devices. Consequently, the `exposurePointOfInterest` will not be set on your desired point.

Your program will not even enter your following snippet of code (you can check yourself):

```
if ([device isExposurePointOfInterestSupported] && [device isExposureModeSupported:exposureMode])
        {
            [device setExposureMode:exposureMode];
            [device setExposurePointOfInterest:point];
        }
```

If you want to have auto expose functionality, what you can do is using `AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExpose` to set the exposure at certain point. Then listen (key-value observe KVO) the `isAdjustingExposure` property of `AVCaptureDevice` to know when the exposure finishes adjusting. As soon as it does, setExposureMode to `AVCaptureExposureModeLocked`.

Please let me know if this doesn't help, otherwise you may accept and upvote this answer :)